# China Finance Minister or China's finance minister?

Tags: grammaticality, headlinese

Today I was reading a newspaper and one thing bugged me that was the headline saying ''China finance minister sees more...''. 
I mean, isn't it going to be "China's finance minister" or either of them is correct? I'm confused.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

"China's Finance Minister" is the correct way to write the position; alternatively "Finance Minister of China" can be used, as can "Chinese Finance Minster".

However, it would not be unusual to see something like that in a newspaper headline. Headlines are generally printed in a MUCH bigger font than the other text to grab attention. This means that the amount of characters that can be used is limited: More characters in the same allocated space necessitates a smaller font.

In order to have the largest font possible, the newspaper has committed a grammatical error (omitting the possessive), but an error whose proper form can be deduced.

Comment: I'm guessing they're actually shortening "finance minister of China". Headlines follow a whole set of their own grammar rules, it's pretty interesting.